# Graph recovery using matrix completion algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, matrix, social-networking

Is there any matrix completion algorithm which can be used to to reconstruct a graph using
only a small number of its edges?

There are many algorithms to recover and complete an unknown matrix which has available only several sampled entries. As far as I know, many of these algorithms work for low rank matrix which is not true about graph adjacency matrix. Like SVT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately many of the natural graph types represented as matrices turn out to be high rank (e.g. trees, cycles and grids). In this sense the problem is not a *matrix completion* problem as stated e.g. in [A SINGULAR VALUE THRESHOLDING ALGORITHM FOR MATRIX COMPLETION](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~candes/papers/SVT.pdf) from Cai, Candes and Shen.

That means, without the contraint of low rankness, the problem is from the prospective of linear algebra ill posed and cannot be solved.